# Scoverage showing 95% coverage coming from 1 test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, code-coverage, scoverage

I am trying to use the Scoverage maven plugin to check code coverage for Scala code.  It seems to be working, except for the fact that 1 test is accounting fro 95%+ of the code coverage.  If I remove this one test, my coverage drops to around 1.5%.  This doesn't seem legitimate.  Not sure what I can post to help or where I should be looking for clues.  Any help is appreciated and I'm happy to update the question along the way.

Comment: This is possible. Compare Scoverage html report for different test subsets or individual tests with what code these tests call.

Comment: How do I get the Scoverage HTML report?  I've been trying to get it to work in SonarQube but with no success.

Comment: Actually nevermind.  I just figured it out based on this: https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/issues/128